# Reverse a string in objective

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, reverse

I am new to coding and objective-c. I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I wonder why my solution doesn't work.

I created a simple challenge for myself: Reverse a string the user typed to `textField` and display the reversed string to console. However this code didn't work, no errors, notifications.

Its seems that `reversedString` just didn't receive anything.

```
- (IBAction)countString:(id)sender {
    NSString *string = [textField stringValue];
    NSUInteger count = [string length];
    [countView setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%lu", string, (unsigned long)count]];
    // Challenge starts here
    NSMutableString *reversedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
    for (NSInteger i = [string length] - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        NSLog(@"%li", (long)i);
        unichar abc = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        NSString *charString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", abc];
        [reversedString stringByAppendingString:charString];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", reversedString);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringByAppendingString:` returns a new `NSString` and in your code the return value is ignored, since you are using a `NSMutableString`, replace

```
[reversedString stringByAppendingString:charString];
```

with

```
[reversedString appendString:charString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method with any objects: NSString,NSNumber,etc..:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self reverseObject:@12345]);
NSLog(@"%@",[self reverseObject:@"Hello World"]);
```

Method:

```
-(NSString*)reverseObject:(id)string{

string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string];
NSMutableString *endString = [NSMutableString new];

while ([string length]!=[endString length]) {
NSRange range = NSMakeRange([string length]-[endString length]-1, 1);
[endString appendString: [string substringWithRange:range]];
}
return endString;
}
```

Log:

2014-04-16 11:20:25.312 TEST[23733:60b] 54321
2014-04-16 11:20:25.313 TEST[23733:60b] dlroW olleH